# SSE with Reactor Core Sinks

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I have a backend application written in Spring Boot, and I have to implement sending of SSE to frontend application. My backend have to support multiple subscribers and to be able to send multiple events to multiple users in the front. Additionally, I have to programmatically trigger the events, so I found it that it can be done with project Reactor Sinks class:

```
private final Map<Long, Many<MyNotification>> sinkMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


public Flux<ServerSentEvent<MyNotification>> createSubscription(Long subscriptionId) {
    Sinks.Many<MyNotification> sink;

    if (sinkMap.get(subscriptionId) != null) {
        sink = sinkMap.get(subscriptionId);
    } else {
        sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
    }

    sinkMap.put(subscriptionId, sink);

    return sink.asFlux().map(event -> ServerSentEvent.builder(event).build());
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is it OK to hold sinks in the map, since I'm figuring out that the application itself will be horizontally scaled? How will it behave in cases of more applications in parallel?
2. Is there a way to somehow "store those sinks" (i.e. Redis or something), so the subscriptions can be centralized?
3. Is there a way to know if subscribers are still subscribed, so that map can be cleared if necessary?
4. Do you have maybe other suggestions for implementation of SSE in Spring Boot, that does not include Reactor Sinks?

Answer (score 2):

First off, your example is not thread safe even though you are using `ConcurrentHashMap`, because you are calling `get` and `put` separately. You should have used `computeIfAbsent` or `compute` to guarantee atomic update of the map in regard to the key.
It is also not clear how long do you plan to keep the sink in the map - whether a single sink will be reused and handed over to new consumers or not. Is the sink unique per consumer?
As far as publishing messages to multiple clients in a cluster is concerned, it depends on what you are trying to do.

1. Yes and no. You can keep the reference in the map as long as you want. Once the subscriber count drops to zero, the sink is dead and must be removed that is unless you disable autoCancel in which case it can be reused.
2. Sink is a handle to a runtime datastructure representing a contract between publisher and subscriber. Do you perhaps want to store recent data that were handed over to the subscriber via the sink? Storing a runtime datastructure encompassing a publishing logic does not make much sense.
3. Yes. This can be done in multitude of ways. The simplest option is to ignore the subscriber count and keep the sink as a singleton forever.
4. Reactor would be the easiest.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm sorry if some parts here makes a little sense to you, I quite new in the world of reactive programming and I have difficulties wrapping my head around it.
My plan is to use unique sink per consumer/subscriber and then if I have i.e. some global notification, my thought was to emit it for each sink sequentially.